# Nuances of meaning between "sich verwirren lassen" and "sich verirren"?

Tags: meaning

> Der unerfahrene Tourist neigt dazu, **sich** von der Vielschichtigkeit der Stadt **verwirren** zu **lassen**.

Compared to:

> Der unerfahrene Tourist neigt dazu, **sich** von der Vielschichtigkeit der Stadt zu **verirren**.

I wonder if the first sentence with *lassen* has the meaning of getting lost ***unwittingly*** or ***at the mercy of*** something, whereas for the second sentence, you venture out into such a maze of streets ***of your own accord***, ***half expecting*** to lose your bearings?

My focus here is on finding out about the connotation perceived with the auxiliary verb *lassen* in an instance like this.

Comment: Maybe you confuse matters? There is a possibility to "sich verirren"

Comment: @Beta Good point! Thanks. In any case, my focus is on finding out about the connotation perceived with the verb "lassen" in an instance like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second sentence is just wrong, or ill-formed.

(Exception: you are a playwright or poet and you misuse or re-frame words on purpose.)

sich von etwas verwirren lassen = get confused by something

As for your question whether the first sentence (which is well-formed) carries a nuance of 'unwittingly' or 'at the mercy of': I would say getting confused is per se unwitting, isn't it? Perhaps you wanted to point at possible differences in meaning of

> (1) sich von jemandem verwirren lassen

vs.

> (2) von jemandem verwirrt werden

Here, I would agree that, yes, you could argue that (2) is more like a neutral constatation whereas (1) has some ironic undertone.

But on the other hand "von jemandem verwirrt werden" is just a little bit awkward as a construction, perhaps due to the odd repetition of sounds:

> Der Tourist **wird** vom Straßennetz ver**wirrt.**

You somehow would avoid such homophony, at least in contexts where some attention to language is desired, e.g. in publishing. Unless you are a poet and use it for a purpose (for example in order to wittingly confuse your audience).

It is more common to say

> Der Tourist wird vom Straßennetz verwirrt.

or, best solution in neutral contexts:

> Der Tourist findet das Straßennetz verwirrend.

Note, however, that 'die Vielschichtigkeit der Stadt' is something quite different from 'the maze of streets'.

Answer (score 2):

Though visually similar both words have a different meaning, usage, and etymology:

> [**verirren**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verirren) *to get lost, to lose orientation*
>    This verb is etymologically related to ***irre*** in the meaning of erroneous, lost in mind or lost in way.
>
> [jmd. **verwirren**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verwirren) *to confuse s.o.*
>    The etymology is related to ***wirr*** in the meaning of confused, puzzled, entangled.